# Chart.js - Setting x-axis based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I am a beginner coder that is just learning chart.js. Can anyone help me understand why my x-axis labels are not adjusting to the user's input after pressing the "generate chart" button? I feel like all my code is correct. Here is my code below.

```
        <td><input type="number" id="StartFreq"/></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="StopFreq"/></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="XTick"/></td>

        </tr>
      </table>
      <button onclick="generateChart()"><strong>Generate Chart</strong></button>
    </section>

    <br>
    <br>
    <section>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
      <script>
      let StartFreq = document.getElementById('StartFreq');
      let StopFreq = document.getElementById('StopFreq');
      let XTick = document.getElementById('XTick');
      let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

      function generateLabels(){
        let xvals = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
          xvals.push(parseFloat(StartFreq.value) + parseFloat(XTick.value) * i )
        }
        return xvals

      }

      let chart = new Chart(ctx, {

      // The type of chart we want to create
      type: 'line',

      // The data for our dataset
      data: {
      labels: generateLabels(),
      datasets: [{
      label: 'R-TE10',
      data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
      }]
      },

      // Configuration options go here
      options: {
        scales : {
          xAxes:[{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }],
          yAxes : [{
            ticks : {
              beginAtZero : true,
              min : 0,
              max: 10
            }
          }]
        }

      }
      });
      function generateChart() {
        generateLabels();
        chart.update()
      }
      </script>
    </section>
```

For clarification, I want the StartFreq to be at the tick at the bottom leftmost part of the chart while my bottom rightmost tick is the Stop Freq. I want each tick to be evenly dispersed and each tick be worth the Xtick input value. I want the chart to update when I click the Generate chart button.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the following

> To update the options, mutating the options property in place or
>   passing in a new options object are supported.

from [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)

For the update to work, you need to mutate the original object, which you are not doing.

just fix it by doing this

```
function generateChart() {
  generateLabels();
  chart.data.labels = generateLabels();
  chart.update();
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/crocsx-the-styleful/pen/JjPzVeK)

Or better, create/show the chart only when you click generate.